# Remove characters from std::string from "(" to ")" with erase ?

Tags: c++, string, std, erase

I want to remove the substring of my string , it looks something like this :

```
At(Robot,Room3)
```

or

```
SwitchOn(Room2)
```

or

```
SwitchOff(Room1)
```

How can I remove all the characters from the left bracket `(` to the right bracket `)` , when I don't know their indexes ?

Comment: Could there be nested parentheses?

Comment: @Shahbaz : No , only a single `(` and a single `)` .

Comment: Are you familiar with [string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you know the string matches the pattern then you can do:

```
std::string str = "At(Robot,Room3)";
str.erase( str.begin() + str.find_first_of("("),
           str.begin() + str.find_last_of(")"));
```

or if you want to be safer

```
auto begin = str.find_first_of("(");
auto end = str.find_last_of(")");
if (std::string::npos!=begin && std::string::npos!=end && begin <= end)
    str.erase(begin, end-begin);
else
    report error...
```

You can also use the standard library `<regex>`.

```
std::string str = "At(Robot,Room3)";
str = std::regex_replace(str, std::regex("([^(]*)\\([^)]*\\)(.*)"), "$1$2");
```

Comment: `1st` suggestion is great ! +1 & chosen .

Comment: Works, but it would be a bit inefficient if you have, say `hugestring(tiny)`, because you're searching the same range twice.

Comment: @KerrekSB Switched to `find_last_of`, though it can still be inefficient, e.g. `tiny(tiny)hugestring`.

Comment: Yeah, same problem. The efficient approach would be to resume searching just past the first parenthesis.

Comment: @KerrekSB But then what about `tiny(hugestring)tiny`? That's not efficient either...

Comment: True, but if you're prepared to extract a large string, then I suppose that cost is acceptable. If you want, you can search forward *and* backwards at once to optimize for both extremes at the expense of the moderate cases. The point is that my initial suggestion is always better than your initial code, though other specific changes may conditionally improve the performance for certain use cases.

Comment: std::string str = "At(Robot,(Room3))"; What happen with this case if you need to remove between brackets and the result expected is At

Comment: @ypriverol Regular expressions aren't powerful enough to deal with matching parentheses, the regex method won't work in that case. The other method works fine because it's just deleting everything between the first opening paren and the last closing paren.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler and standard library is new enough, then you could use [`std::regex_replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace).

Otherwise, you search for the first `'('`, do a reverse search for the last `')'`, and use [`std::string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) to remove everything in between. Or if there can be nothing after the closing parenthesis then find the first and use [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to extract the string you want to keep.

If the trouble you have is actually *finding* the parentheses the use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and/or [`std::string::rfind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind).

Answer (score 1):

You have to search for the first '(' then erase after until 'str.length() - 1' (assuming your second bracket is always at the end)

Answer (score 1):

A simple *and safe and efficient* solution:

```
std::string str = "At(Robot,Room3)";

size_t const open = str.find('(');
assert(open != std::string::npos && "Could not find opening parenthesis");

size_t const close = std.find(')', open);
assert(open != std::string::npos && "Could not find closing parenthesis");

str.erase(str.begin() + open, str.begin() + close);
```

Never parse a character more than once, beware of ill-formed inputs.